# How do you Bubble Sort Largest to Smallest

Tags: java, sorting

Sorry am kind of lame at this. I've looked on here for a way to Bubble sort so that I can get an array to go from largest number to smallest. I've found some error in my current iteration of the sort, I can't seem to get the array to sort once it compares a smaller number to a bigger number. Here what I am using thus far.

```
//bubble sort
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(int v=1;i<(size-i);i++)
        {
            if(arrInt[v-1]<arrInt[v])
            {
                temp = arrInt[v-1];
                arrInt[v-1]=arrInt[v];
                arrInt[v]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the second `for`, why did you use `i` ?

Comment: oh crap, thanks for the eagle eyes man!

Comment: shouldn't your 2nd for loop be for(int v=1;v<(size-i);v++)?

Comment: Yeah, just tried that and am still not getting accurate sortings. Have any other suggestions?

Comment: I tried your code after above correction in inner loop, & it works perfectly.however, if you're having problem, I suggest you to check whats 'size' value...It should be the no of elements in your array.

Comment: @CristianReyes you should accept a suitable answer if it answers your question. This motivates community to answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
int n = arrInt.length;
int temp = 0;    
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   for (int v = 1; v < (n - i); v++) {
       if (arrInt[v - 1] < arrInt[v]) {
          temp = arrInt[v - 1];
          arrInt[v - 1] = arrInt[v];
          arrInt[v] = temp;
       }

   }
}
```

Try this. 
**Update** - Replaced j with v

Comment: For largest to smallest(as per question) line 3 should be `if (arrInt[j - 1] < arrInt[j])` and not `>`

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I posted but with j replaced with v. I even switched line 3 and am still having issues.

Comment: I found the issue! If you look at my code you will see that for the second for loop I made the mistake of putting i++ instead of v++. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the inner loop should be from 1 to n. Instead your inner loop stops early.

Also you are testing i in the inner loop condition, but you should be testing v.

Try this:

```
//bubble sort
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    for(int v=1;v<size;v++)
    {
        if(arrInt[v-1]<arrInt[v])
        {
            temp = arrInt[v-1];
            arrInt[v-1]=arrInt[v];
            arrInt[v]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Bubble Sort Method for Descending Order`

```
public static void BubbleSort( int[ ] arr){
    int records=arr.length-1;
    boolean notSorted= true;   // first pass
    while (notSorted) {
        notSorted= false;    //set flag to false awaiting a possible swap
        for( int count=0;  count < records;  count++ ) {
            if ( arr[count] < arr[count+1] ) {  // change to > for ascending sort
                arr[count]=arr[count]+arr[count+1];
                arr[count+1]=arr[count]-arr[count+1];
                arr[count]=arr[count]-arr[count+1];
                notSorted= true;     //Need to further check        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this method when array is sorted then it does not check further.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I implement Bubble sort like this,

```
for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++) {
    for(int v=0;v<(size-1-i);v++){
        if(arrInt[v]<arrInt[v+1])
        {
            temp = arrInt[v];
            arrInt[v]=arrInt[v+1];
            arrInt[v+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

You know what is the problem is, in your code??? Look at the inner loop, you are initializing `v` but checking and changing `i`. Must be a copy paste error.. :P

Hope it helped...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
int x = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
        if(array[i] > array[j + 1])
            x = array[j + 1];
            array[j + 1]= array[i];
            array[i] = x;
```

`x` here is a temporary variable you only need for this operation.

Answer (score 0):

here's a complete running program for you. Hope that keeps you motivated

```
package test;

public class BubbleSort {

private static int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 45, 65, 89, -98, 2, 75 };

public static void sortBubbleWay() {
    int size = arr.length-1;
    int temp = 0; // helps while swapping
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[j+1]) { /* For decreasing order use < */
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void showShortedArray() {
    for (int elt : arr) {
        System.out.println(elt);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    sortBubbleWay();
    showShortedArray();
}
}//end of class
```